# jQuery - Need to select next 7 elements with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is I am using the date picker and have the bookable days with a class of .bookable and the non bookable ones a class of .non_bookable as follows:

```
    <tr>
   <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled not_bookable" title="This date is unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">7</span></td>
   <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled not_bookable" title="This date is unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">8</span></td>
   <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled not_bookable" title="This date is unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">9</span></td>
   <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled not_bookable" title="This date is unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">10</span></td>
   <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled not_bookable" title="This date is unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">11</span></td>
   <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled not_bookable" title="This date is unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">12</span></td>
   <td class="ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-days-cell-over bookable" title="This date is available" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="10" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">13</a></td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is select the next 7 elements with the .non_bookable class after the one with the .bookable class.

I am trying just to select the next one (before I even try the next 7!) but can't seem to be able to do this, I believe because it's up a level and in the next  tag. The code I am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery('tr .bookable').closest('tr .not_bookable').css('background','green');
});
```

I have all the code in full at  jsfiddle.net/jmkqza5f/2

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATE - As you will see on the Fiddle, it is applying the style to the previous elements rather than the next elements.

Comment: ,find? you know what that does, right? sigh...

Comment: So by "the next 7 elements" you mean the next 7 td elements regardless of which tr they belong to? Your fiddle didn't include jQuery - adding it produced a result with some green cells: https://jsfiddle.net/jmkqza5f/2/

Comment: Yes, I was trying it as I saw it on another post here on Stack Overflow - edited the code now to what I was using previously

Comment: you're just throwing methods around hoping they work... read the documentation for those methods..

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be selecting the days before, I need it to do the days next

Comment: you don't have any next, they're all before. you know about the next and prev methods, right? and their nextAll and prevAll equivalents? they're all in the docs.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for being so helpful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. The way your current code is set up, it is looking for the closest table row, which in this case is the parent element.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery('tr .bookable').parents('tr').next('tr').find('.not_bookable').css('background','green');
});
```

Comment: @JamesLeist you should fix it so it works 
on the actual site.

Comment: @KevinB - that's exactly what i'm doing :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

        jQuery('tr .bookable').closest('tr').next().find('.not_bookable').css('background','green');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a simple selector question.  I"m going to propose an alternative solution that may help you better.  You are most likely generating those classes using the jQuery Datepicker method [beforeShowDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay).  I would suggest to extend the before show date to add another class.  So instead of "bookable" and "not_bookable" there is an additional class "recently_booked".  You then do the logic in the same place where you added those classes previously.